# Create SVF Plugin throws invalid param exception

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

I'm working on a Inventor appbundle that loads the create SVF Plugin , updates few parameters in the model and create a SVF2 file which I will be viewing later. So the issue is when I try to save an SVF file I get Invalid parameter exception. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance. Attaching code snippet.

```
try
                {
                    ApplicationAddIn svfAddin = m_server
                        .ApplicationAddIns
                        .Cast<ApplicationAddIn>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.ClassIdString == "{C200B99B-B7DD-4114-A5E9-6557AB5ED8EC}");

                    var oAddin = (TranslatorAddIn)svfAddin;

                    if (oAddin != null)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("SVF Translator addin is available");
                        TranslationContext oContext = m_server.TransientObjects.CreateTranslationContext();
                        // Setting context type
                        oContext.Type = IOMechanismEnum.kFileBrowseIOMechanism;

                        NameValueMap oOptions = m_server.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap();
                        // Create data medium;
                        DataMedium oData = m_server.TransientObjects.CreateDataMedium();

                        Trace.TraceInformation("SVF save");
                        var sessionDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "SvfOutput");
                        oData.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(sessionDir, "result.collaboration");
                        var outputDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(sessionDir, "output");
                        var bubbleFileOriginal = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputDir, "bubble.json");
                        var bubbleFileNew = System.IO.Path.Combine(sessionDir, "bubble.json");

                        // Setup SVF options
                        if (oAddin.get_HasSaveCopyAsOptions(Doc, oContext, oOptions))
                        {
                            oOptions.set_Value("GeometryType", 1);
                            oOptions.set_Value("EnableExpressTranslation", true);
                            oOptions.set_Value("SVFFileOutputDir", sessionDir);
                            oOptions.set_Value("ExportFileProperties", true);
                            oOptions.set_Value("ObfuscateLabels", false);
                        }

                        LogTrace($"SVF files are output to: {oOptions.get_Value("SVFFileOutputDir")}");

if(!Directory.Exists(sessionDir))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(sessionDir);
                            LogTrace("Directory created");
                        }

                        oAddin.SaveCopyAs(Doc, oContext, oOptions, oData);
                        Trace.TraceInformation("SVF can be exported.");
                        LogTrace($"** Saved SVF as {oData.FileName}");
                        System.IO.File.Move(bubbleFileOriginal, bubbleFileNew);

                        string zipPath = outputZipFile;
                        ZipFolder(sessionDir, zipPath);

                        if(System.IO.File.Exists(zipPath))
                        {
                            LogTrace("Zip created");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogTrace($"********Export to format SVF failed: {e.Message}");
                }
```

The exception exactly is - The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) and I'm trying to get an SVF2 file.

```
Logtrace of workitem:
[05/16/2023 08:37:07] Starting work item <...>
[05/16/2023 08:37:07] Start download phase.
[05/16/2023 08:37:07] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/<...>'
[05/16/2023 08:37:07] Embedded resource [ {'browserConnectionId':'dG86hPu4eKngXcsy4Ycy0w','useCache':false,'keepWorkitem':false,'params':{},'screenshot':{'width':1236,'height':847}}] is saved as a file in 'Unicode' at: 'T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\params.json'.
[05/16/2023 08:37:13] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/<...>,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\zip_31.zip,BytesDownloaded=225378628,Duration=5740ms
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\zip_31.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\<...>.
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] End download phase successfully.
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\895b47da1b160a025fb2b06b74016def.pQHzjERS2mVkQNCKBmWwvCvJecOdhgdB.UpdateIPTParam[6].package"]
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] Start script phase.
[05/16/2023 08:37:15] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0, 15-e376d5d
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to get Inventor Server version in use.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 26, 20, 28702, 0001.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is older than 2023
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2022.2 (Build 262287010, 287A) (26, 20, 28702, 0001)
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting up iLogicLogLevelTo: Warn
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting Inventor plug-in.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateIPTParam (1.0.0.8): initializing... 
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Executing 'Run' method on Automation object.
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : ** Saving SVF
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF Translator addin is available
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF save
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF files are output to: T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\SvfOutput
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : ********Export to format SVF failed: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateIPTParam
[05/16/2023 08:37:16]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateIPTParam: deactivating... 
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] CoreConsole Dispose start
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] CoreConsole ReleaseAll start
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] CoreConsole ReleaseAll end
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] CoreConsole Dispose end
[05/16/2023 08:37:16] CoreConsole exiting (0)
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] End script phase.
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] Start upload phase.
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] Error: Non-optional output [output.zip] is missing.
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[05/16/2023 08:37:17] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
```

CreateActivity:

```
if (OAuthController.GetAppSetting("DISABLE_SETUP") == "true")
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CreateActivity");


                List<string> allActivities = new List<string>();
                string paginationToken = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    Page<string> activities = await _designAutomation.GetActivitiesAsync(paginationToken);
                    allActivities.AddRange(activities.Data);
                    if (activities.PaginationToken == null)
                        break;
                    paginationToken = activities.PaginationToken;
                }

                if (!allActivities.Contains(QualifiedBundleActivityName))
                {
                    string commandLine = CommandLine();
                    Activity activitySpec = new Activity()
                    {
                        Id = kBundleActivityName,
                        Appbundles = new List<string>() { QualifiedBundleActivityName },
                        CommandLine = new List<string>() { commandLine },
                        Engine = kEngineName,
                        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, Parameter>()
                    {
                        { "inputFile", new Parameter() { Description = "input file", LocalName = "<>", Ondemand = false, Required = true, Verb = Verb.Get, Zip = false } },
                        { "inputJson", new Parameter() { Description = "input json", LocalName = "params.json", Ondemand = false, Required = false, Verb = Verb.Get, Zip = false } },
                        { "outputFile", new Parameter() { Description = "output file", LocalName = "output.zip", Ondemand = false, Required = true, Verb = Verb.Put, Zip = false } }
                    }
                    };
                    Activity newActivity = await _designAutomation.CreateActivityAsync(activitySpec);

                    // specify the alias for this Activity
                    Alias aliasSpec = new Alias() { Id = Alias, Version = 1 };
                    Alias newAlias = await _designAutomation.CreateActivityAliasAsync(kBundleActivityName, aliasSpec);

                    return Ok(new { Activity = QualifiedBundleActivityName });
                }

                return Ok(new { Activity = "Activity already defined" });
```

CreateWorkitem:

```
// 1. input file
                XrefTreeArgument inputFileArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
                {
                    //Url = "adsk.objects:os.object:" + BucketKey + "/" + "<>",
                    Url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/" + BucketKey + "/objects/" + "<>",
                    PathInZip = "<>",
                    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                    { "Authorization", "Bearer " + oauth.access_token} }
                };

                // 2. input json
                //dynamic inputJson = new JObject();
                XrefTreeArgument inputJsonArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
                {
                    Url = "data:application/json, " + ((JObject)input).ToString(Formatting.None).Replace("\"", "'")
                };
                // 3. output file
                string outputFileNameOSS = string.Format("{0}_output_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"), "<>"); // avoid overriding            
                XrefTreeArgument outputFileArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
                {
                    Url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/" + BucketKey + "/objects/" + zipFileName,
                    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "Authorization", "Bearer " + oauth.access_token}
                },
                    Verb = Verb.Put
                };

                string callbackComplete = string.Format(
                    "{0}/api/forge/callback/oncomplete?id={1}&outputFile={2}",
                    OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL"),
                    browserConnectionId,
                    zipFileName);

                WorkItem workItemSpec = new WorkItem()
                {
                    ActivityId = QualifiedBundleActivityName,
                    Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>()
                {
                    { "inputFile", inputFileArgument },
                    { "inputJson",  inputJsonArgument },
                    { "outputFile", outputFileArgument },
                    { "onComplete", new XrefTreeArgument { Verb = Verb.Post, Url = callbackComplete } }
                }
                };
                WorkItemStatus workItemStatus = await _designAutomation.CreateWorkItemAsync(workItemSpec);
```

Comment: I see you are using the same code we do in our example, except of the zipping which I wouldn't do, but I would say is not causing issue you see. Can you put here masked log file from workitem processing?

Comment: @MichalVasicek Have edited the post to add the tracelog

Comment: Did you make sure that the folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\8081eec5293e4ac2bd925247943e3299\SvfOutput" exists? In many samples it's DA taking care of that, bacause the activity has an output parameter with zip=true and localName="SvfOutput" values, so that folder will be created automatically.

Comment: Yes I created the directory. still having the same error.

Comment: Where are you creating it? I don't see it in your code

Comment: @AdamNagy Sorry forgot to edit the code. Now done.

Comment: Do you run into this with ANY model? Could you try to narrow it down? e.g. don't do anything in the app bundle apart from generating SVF, and use a most simple part file.
If that still does not help then contact aps.help@autodesk.com and we could have a meeting

Comment: @AdamNagy Yes I tried it with a simple part and still with the same result. I'll mail to said email address.

Comment: One thing my colleague suggested is that in your case Doc might be null (i.e. you're not actually opening a document) - could you please add a test code for that?

Comment: Yes exactly. Resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not opening any document. It means your Doc variable is null and your call to oAddin.SaveCopyAs(Doc, oContext, oOptions, oData); is called on nothing. That is the reason why there is Invalid Parameter error.

Comment: Yes did. Still the error persists. Have modified the post with my code to CreateActivity and Workitem.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine except that the model didn't open in the Inventor Server which threw the invalid param exception. I manually opened the assembly fine with 2 lines of code and it's worked fine. Thank you all for support.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).